# Unable to connect spring-boot docker container to another node-js docker container

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, graphql

I have 5 docker container, start using docker-compose, I am able to connect from my 2 react connect to backend server, but my spring-boot backend is unable to connect to graphql-node-js app with below error:

Here is the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  #node-js app
  socketserver:
    image: quiz-roulette/socket-server
    ports:
        - "30100:80"
  #graphql-node-js app
  questionbankserver:
    image: quiz-roulette/question-bank-graphql-server
    ports:
      - "34000:4000"
  #spring-boot app
  legacyserver:
    image: quiz-roulette/legacy-server
    ports:
        - "33000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - questionbankserver
    links:
      - "questionbankserver:questionbank"
  #react-js-app
  playergame:
    image: quiz-roulette/player-game
    ports:
        - "32000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - legacyserver
        - socketserver
  #react-js-app
  livedashboard:
    image: quiz-roulette/live-dashboard
    ports:
        - "31000:80"
    depends_on:
        - legacyserver
        - socketserver
```

Please note, the below error is when `legacyserver` is trying to connect to `questionbankserver`

error log:

```
legacyserver_1        | 2021-05-18 13:56:57.804  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
legacyserver_1        | 2021-05-18 13:56:57.804  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
legacyserver_1        | 2021-05-18 13:56:57.805  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
legacyserver_1        | 2021-05-18 13:56:58.416 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.q.L.q.QuestionBankClient               : Failed to connect to questionbank/172.22.0.3:34000
legacyserver_1        | 2021-05-18 13:56:58.435 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
legacyserver_1        | 
legacyserver_1        | java.lang.NullPointerException: null
legacyserver_1        |         at com.quizroulette.LegacyServer.question_bank_adapter.QuestionBankAdapter.getQuestions(QuestionBankAdapter.java:30) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
legacyserver_1        |         at com.quizroulette.LegacyServer.QuestionController.getQuestions(QuestionController.java:29) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
legacyserver_1        |         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
legacyserver_1        |
```

Also note, when I am trying to connect via normal localhost to localhost without docker, i am getting successful response.

In order not to grow this question long, I have avoided the pieces of code. However please let me know if you need further info

Comment: The exception isn't really meaningful without any code to go along with it.  What's the URL you're trying to connect to?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is trying to connect http://questionbank:34000 however I have also tried using http://localhost:34000 but none works.

Comment: Connections between containers ignore `ports:`.  Use the "standard" port number, `http://questionbankserver:4000`.

Comment: That worked. thanks.